# Continuity of pr a function defined by an definite integral

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, definite-integrals, continuity

Let $f \in {L^2}({(0,1)^2})$ , we defined $F$ by $$F(x) = \int\limits_0^1 {f(s,x)ds} $$
What can I say about the continuity of $F$?.
I think as the following: let $x_0 \in L^2(0,1)$, and let $(x_n)$ be a sequence converging to $x$ in $L^2(0,1)$, by the dominate convergence theorem, we can pass to the limit. Is this correct ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, your assert is certainly **false**. The correct assumptions are:

- For every $x\in [0, 1]$ set $g_x(s)=f(s, x)$ we must have $g_x\in L^1([0, 1])$. Now because $[0, 1]$ has finite measure we have $L^2[0, 1]\subseteq L^1[0, 1]$ then your $f$ satisfy this assertion;
- For *almost* every $s\in [0, 1]$ the function $h_s(x)=f(s, x)$ must be **continue** on all $[0, 1]$ and $f$ doesn't usually satisfy it.

For example take $f(s, x)$ such that 
$$
f(s, x)=\begin{cases}
0 &\text{ if }x=0\\
1 &\text{ if }x>0
\end{cases}
$$
then $f\in L^2\left([0, 1]^2\right)$ but
$$
F(x)=\begin{cases}
0 &\text{ if }x=0\\
1 &\text{ if }x>0
\end{cases}
$$
and $F$ isn't continue.

You need $f$ **continue** respect to $x$ in order to prove $F$ continuity.

Comment: Thank you sir..